# Session aborting while loading library iplots

Tags: r, rstudio, rjava, iplots

I tried to load the library `Deducer`, and while doing so the packages `ggplot`, `JGR`, `rJava`, and `JavaGD` were loading successfully, but my R-session is aborting when plotting.

Comment: Describe how your “R-session is aborting”. Do you get an error message? Tell it to us.

Comment: How are you running R, through Rstudio, Eclipse, natively...?

Answer (score -1):

```
db <- available.packages()    
deps <- tools::package_dependencies("Deducer", db)$Deducer
install.packages(deps)
```

Comment: Explain your solution please.